# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL caused by \u2028 and \u2029

Tags: php, javascript

I am sending a sting as a parameter to a JavaScript function:

```
theJSFunction('say hi dude');
```

Chrome gives me `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` so after research, I've found that the following whitespaces generates the error `\u2028` and `\u2029`.

The problem is, the string posted to the function is printed via PHP and I need it to be printed via PHP (could use ajax, but I am required to let the PHP print it).

Is there any way to remove those to characters through PHP or JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace with `.replace`. Passing a regular expressions with the `g` flag replaces all occurences, and you can include `\uxxxx` characters as well:

```
"\u2028\u2029".replace(/\u2028|\u2029/g, "").length; // 0
```

Comment: Fixed , `str_replace("\n",'',$string); str_replace("\r",'',$string);`